# Cxf jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors unable to modify message

Tags: java, spring, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

Here is my fault interceptor:

```
public class OutFaultInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

   public OutFaultInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SEND);
    }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault 
        {   
            Fault fault = (Fault)message.getContent(Exception.class);
            Throwable ex = fault.getCause();
            Response response = JAXRSUtils.convertFaultToResponse(ex, message);
            message.setContent(Response.class, response);
    }
}
```

Here is my relevant cxf-config:

```
    <jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors>
        <bean id="outfault" class="com.xxx.OutFaultInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors>
```

I can get into the handleMessage method no problem, but I'm not able to modify the message.

Currently what it returns is the default: ns1:XMLFault blah blah...

What I want to return is a Response object that has a proper HTTP response code and a json body (which I correctly have in my response variable above).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using JAX-RS, why not setup an exception mapper, and then use that mapper to handle the response.

A simple example:

```
 @Provider
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class MyExceptionMapper implements
            ExceptionMapper<MyException> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(MyException e) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

    }
```

Then you would need to register the provider in the jaxrs serve by adding:

```
<jaxrs:providers>
    <bean class="com.blah.blah.blah.blah.MyExceptionMapper"/>  
</jaxrs:providers>
```

in the server config in the context. With that you have full access to the exception, and can get whatever you want from it.

Comment: I am using apache cxf with apache camel in redhat fuse esb. i am using 2.6.0.redhat-60024 for cxf jars provided by redhat, although 2.7.0 version is also available for cxf jars but the ExceptionMapper you suggested is available after 2.7.8(as per cxf doc), so i can not use your suggested codes, can you please suggest me any other way to solve the same issue...